# R: Default values in nested lists

Tags: r, nested-lists

I am currently building a reccursive loop in R, where I have to keep track of how deep I am in a nested list. I, however, have run into problems when counting in nested lists.

Here is the problem illustrated:

I have a list

```
myList <- list()
```

I test the value of a random index in the list

```
myList[["test1"]]

NULL
```

I can sum this value and get zero

```
sum(myList[["test1"]])

0
```

Now I assign a value to this index

```
myList[["test1"]] <- sum(myList[["test1"]]) + 1
```

Next I want to do the same just deeper into the list

```
myList[["test1"]][["test2"]]

Error in myList[["test1"]][["test2"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because myList[["test1"]] is NULL. You can't subset a NULL. It would help if you described why you want to do this...

Comment: I have a number of nested lists that it need to count the nodes across. To do so I have written a recursive function that goes through the lists, and then store the output in another nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the value of `myList[["test1"]]` with...

```
myList[["test1"]] <- sum(myList[["test1"]]) + 1
```

`myList[["test1"]]` becomes a 1 element numeric vector, not a list

If you want to make `test1` a list, with one of its elements being another (sub)list called `test2`, you can do this...

```
myList <- list()
myList[["test1"]] <- list(sum(myList[["test1"]]) + 1)
myList[["test1"]]["test2"] <- list(sum(myList[["test1"]][[1]]) + 1)

myList
myList$test1
myList$test1$test2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this is a simpler version of what you did:

```
> x<-1
> x[["test2"]]
Error in x[["test2"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Here `x` is a numeric vector. It can still be subscripted using `[[` but there is no element named `test2` in `x`, so you get an "out of bounds" error when you try to access that element.

Even a vector with more than one element would give this error:

```
> c(1,2)[["test2"]]
Error in c(1, 2)[["test2"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

However, if we name one of them `test2` then the subscripting returns something:

```
> c(1,2,test2=3)[["test2"]]
[1] 3
```